# Can i force a bonsai to branch?

Tags: bonsai, branches

I have a bonsai ash but would like stone lower branches on the tree. Can I force the mini-tree to make any?

Comment: please add a picture or two

Answer (score 1):

On younger branches you can sometimes remove a sliver of bark above a likely bud which might force it to expand. Otherwise you have a good chance that regular pruning of the bonsai will at some point encourage a side growth that you can wire into place to fill a gap.

Comment: And if that fails to give one the desired branch, it is possible to graft a branch in that place.

Comment: Thank you all, much appreciated.